# Ubuntu 18.04 UEFI - This is not a bootable disk error

Tags: boot, 18.04, uefi

I've been experiencing this problem for hours and don't know how to fix this.

I have a **ASUS H81M-C motherboard** and **Ubuntu 18.04** (only) freshly installed on my MBR drive. But since the first time it was installed, it couldn't boot the OS. My screen only print a white on black text says "*This is not a bootable disk. Please insert a bootable floopy disk.....*".

I have updated my BIOS setting to **UEFI mode** and changed the **Secure Boot to "Other OS"** mode but it still shows me the same error.

I've also tried to repair the boot using the **boot-repair**, still no result. What should I do to fix this?

Here is the link to the boot-repair pastebin log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hV93NzGHzM/

Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually the problem was because the MBR partitioning on my drive. I need to change my drive to GPT partition first in order for Ubuntu to boot in UEFI mode.

Hopefully this answer helps someone.

Comment: And how did you do that? Linking to other answers that describe that would have been nice.